# which oxygen atom make intramolecular hydrogen bond in salicyclic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, hydrogen-bond

[image: Two forms of intramolecular hydrogen bonding in Salicylic acid]

When I googled about intramolecular hydrogen bonding in Salicylic acid, I found that there are two type of hydrogen bonding. Which one is more appropriate?

And another question, if there ARE two types of hydrogen bonding, why doesn't the 15.2 ppm peak of NMR specturm doesn't split in two? It seems that the two form of hydrogen bonding has diffrent energy level.